# CMake Vscode Unable to debug build works fine but debug had problem

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, gdb

I have been working with CMake extension from 1 month with Vscode. Now I am facing a problem that it stops debugging the building works fine but after this`

```
[main] Building folder: Game of Life GameOfLife
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build "f:/Projects/C++/program2021/Game of Life/build" --config Debug --target GameOfLife -j 10 --
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target GameOfLife
[build] [100%] Built target GameOfLife
[build] Build finished with exit code 0
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe" --version
[proc] Executing command: gdb --version
```

So after the gdb --version line the debugging stops.

Comment: The obvious question/troubleshooting: Is the gdb command successful when run manually?

Comment: yes manually form gdb it runs fine but from cmake it stop at gdb --version

Comment: if you have a launch.json file could you share it ?